# How do I use bootstrap classes to hide some text in the h1 tag?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<h1> Web Design is Awesome!!!<span class="visible-lg">(I Guess...)</span></h1>
```

"I guess" shows up in all screen sizes. I want it to show only on large screens. Can anyone help me.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: Does this help? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: I believe from the classes that he mentioned in the code, he is using Bootstrap v3.0+ and docs are related to v4.0 which has changed the display classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **hidden-md** along with **visible-lg**

check [Responsive Utilities](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp) section for more detail

Answer (score 0):

Add `visible-lg-inline` to the `span`. then it will be visible only in large screens.

```html
<h1> Web Design is Awesome!!!<span class="visible-lg-inline">(I Guess...)</span></h1>
```